# How to print only unique non repeated values in a HashSet in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashset

The code below gives the output as One Two Three. **But I need to print only the unique non repeated element i.e Three which has occured only once**.
To be more clear from a arrayList of say 1,2,3,3,2,4,5,5,4,6,6,7, I need to get only 1,7 which are not repeated.

````
ArrayList<String> aListNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        aListNumbers.add("One");
        aListNumbers.add("Two");
        aListNumbers.add("One");
        aListNumbers.add("Two");
        aListNumbers.add("Three");
  
        HashSet<String> hSetNumbers = new HashSet(aListNumbers);
        System.out.println("ArrayList Unique Values");
        for(String strNumber : hSetNumbers)
            System.out.println(strNumber); ```
````

Comment: `hSetNumbers` already has unique values.

Comment: I know it has unique values. But I need to print  non-repeated unique value from arrayList like from 1,2,2,3,5,6,6,2,2 I want only 1.

Comment: `Set<String> uniqueNumbers = aListNumbers.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());` I'm assuming `aListNumbers` is a `List`

Comment: What do you mean by `non-repeated unique`. Can you give an example of how is now and how you want?

Comment: non-repeated unique in sense that from suppose arrayList of 1,2,3,5,6,2,3,5,7,6. I need only 1 and 7 in hashset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every other answer does unnecessary computation or uses more memory than needed, so:

```java
Map<String, Long> counted  = aListNumbers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(el -> el, Collectors.counting()));

counted.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == 1)
    .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey()));
```

Comment: You are also doing more calculations than needed. Consider `Map<String, Boolean> noDuplicates = aListNumbers.stream() .collect(Collectors.toMap(el -> el, el -> true, (a,b) -> false));`. Then `noDuplicates.entrySet().stream() .filter(Map.Entry::getValue) .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey()));`

Answer (score 2):

You can first use a grouping-by collector and then filter those list with exactly one element:

```
List<String> aListNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
aListNumbers.add("One");
aListNumbers.add("Two");
aListNumbers.add("One");
aListNumbers.add("Two");
aListNumbers.add("Three");

aListNumbers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .filter(l -> l.size() == 1)
        .map(l -> l.get(0))
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

**Edit**:
Just thought of another method which i find slighty more elegant:

```
aListNumbers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use streams for that job:

```
Set<String> hSetNumbers = aListNumbers.stream().distinct()
        .filter(num1 -> aListNumbers.stream().filter(num1::equals).count() == 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

hSetNumbers.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the elements from the stream (derived from the list) whose frequency is `1`.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> aListNumbers = new ArrayList<>(List.of("One", "Two", "Three", "One", "Two"));
        Set<String> hSetNumbers = aListNumbers
                                .stream()
                                .filter(e -> Collections.frequency(aListNumbers, e) == 1)
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        System.out.println(hSetNumbers);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Three]
```